# rails-jquery ujs handlers aren't attached to elements inserted via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a set up where there are comments rendered on page load, then another area also with comments which is rendered with an ajax request, using `.load()`.

The async loaded comments all have the same new form structure, but jquery-ujs isn't picking up on the comments rendered through the ajax request.

It doesn't seem like this is related to this [rails-jquery github issue](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/223) since the UJS handlers aren't even picking up the new elements for which my ajax lisetenrs should be fired from.

The problem is that the form is submited / redirected to the create action (not through, but to), thus it's clear the jquery-ujs handlers aren't picking up the form elements added through the ajax request.

I'm on Rails 3.2 with jquery-rails 3.1.1.

Is this a bug on jquery-rails or something else perhaps?

Here's some relevant code:

controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

end
```

form partial for overview and async comments, form is submitted with the 'Add' button

```
<%= form_for :comment,
  url: project_comments_path(@project),
  html: { :class => "newcommentform", style: "display:none" },
  method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment_text,
      { rows: 5, cols: 30, disabled: true, html: { style: "width: 100%"} } %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :section, value: section %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id, value: @project.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type, value: comment_type %>
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="newcommentcancel">Cancel</a>
    <%= f.submit "Add", remote: true, method: :post, :class => 'newcommentform', data: {type: 'html'} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The fact you have all the `remote: true, method: :post, :class => 'newcommentform', data: {type: 'html'}` gumf duplicated on your submit button makes me think you're doing something to handle the submit yourself in JS rather than letting rails ujs do its thing. Why's that there?

Comment: I have since realized that I have a nested form causing this trouble.  I will post back with my fix when I have it.

Comment: Turns out I needed to submit a partial form and was confusedly expecting Rails to submit that for me, inline with the UJS handlers.